# ¿Por qué keyTyped no reconoce el último dígito que ingreso?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Necesito que cada vez que tipee una letra (keyTyped), se llame al void contar().
El void contar() contará los digitos que ingrese en un JtextField y mostrará la cantidad de letras Mayúsculas, Minúsculas y Números.

```
void contar(){
  char caracter;
  String textoIngresado;
  textoIngresado = JTextField1.getText();
  int contNumero=0 ,contLetraMay=0 , contLetraMin=0;

            for(int i=0;i<textoIngresado.length();i++){

                    caracter = textoIngresado.charAt(i);

            //Convierto a String el caracter    
            String x = String.valueOf(caracter); 

                //si es mayúscula
                if(x.matches("[A-Z]")){
                    contLetraMay++;

                    //si es minúscula
                    }else if (x.matches("[a-z]")){
                    contLetraMin++;

                    //si es un número
                    }else if(x.matches("[0-9]")){
                    contNumero++;
                }

            }
  System.out.println("Caracteres en el JTexField : "+textoIngresado.length());
  System.out.println("Cantidad de letras mayusculas : "+contLetraMay);
  System.out.println("Cantidad de letras minusculas : "+contLetraMin);
  System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros : "+contNumero);
}
```

Si ingreso en el JtextField la letra "a" minúscula
el resultado es :

> Caracteres en el JTextField : 0
>     Cantidad de letras mayusculas : 0
>     Cantidad de letras minusculas : 0
>     Cantidad de numeros : 0

No me reconoce el caracter que acabo de ingresar.

Sin embargo, si escribo "a4"
el resultado es :

> Caracteres en el JTextField : 1
>     Cantidad de letras mayusculas : 0
>     Cantidad de letras minusculas : 1
>     Cantidad de numeros : 0

si escribo "a4Z" :

> Caracteres en el JTextField : 2
>     Cantidad de letras mayusculas : 0
>     Cantidad de letras minusculas : 1
>     Cantidad de numeros : 1

es decir, no cuenta el último caracter que ingreso.
Pero si llamo al método contar() desde un botón, si cuenta todos los caracteres que se encuentran en el JTextField.
¿Por qué ocurre esto y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Prueba con `keyReleased`, funciona como uno esperaría en este caso particular. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! me sirvió mucho, aún no comprendo muy bien la diferencia entre keyTyped y KeyReleased.